# como incluir letras na minha list no python e informar ao usuário que a mesma foi repetida

Tags: python-3.x, lista, if, else, print

```
for letra in palavra_secreta:
    #print(inclui_Letras)
    if (chute == letra):
        letras_acertadas[index] = letra
        inclui_Letras.append(letra)  # incluir o 'chute' na list 'inclui_letras
        print(palavra_secreta, chute, letra, inclui_Letras)
    index += 1
```

Estou usando esse código para verificar se há uma letra colocada pelo usuário em uma palavra. Porém, vamos supor que minha palavra seja 'Morango' e eu coloquei a letra A. Nesse caso está tudo certo, mas... eu repetir a letra A diversas vezes e quero informar ao usuário (print) que já foi colocado a referida letra.

No código acima tentei adicionar todas as letras na tag incluir_Letras, mas a mesma só esta adicionando a última letra e assim não consigo fazer uma comparação.

[image: Segue imagem do erro do código]

Answer (score 0):

Não sei bem se era o que vocẽ queria. Mas me parece que você está implementando um joguinho de uma palavra secreta, o jogador vai chutando a letra até formar a palavra, e se ele repetir a letra, uma mensagem informa que a letra já foi escolhida. Então implementei algo abaixo, veja se satisfaz a sua necessidade:

```
palavra_secreta = "morango"
letra_digitada=[]
palavra_formada=[None]*len(palavra_secreta)
while(True):
    l_d = str(input("Digite uma letra"))
    if l_d in letra_digitada:
        print('você já escolheu essa letra')
        continue
    else:
        letra_digitada.append(l_d)
        for idx,item in enumerate(palavra_secreta):
            if l_d==item:
                palavra_formada[idx]=item
    if None not in palavra_formada:
        print("Você conseguiu!! A palvara formada é \n {}".format(''.join(palavra_formada)))
        break
```